# Nested case when: count check then format check

Tags: sql, group-by, case, aggregate-functions, teradata

I'm in TeraData, I have two fields f1, f2 and need the following logic:

```
    sel
         'blah' as x1,
          case when count(distinct f1) = count(distinct f2)
                 then(case when char(trim(f1)) between 1 and 25
                             then 'OK'
                           else 'DEFECT_1'
                      end)
               else 'DEFECT_2'
             end as x2,
           count(x2) as x3
     from table
     group by 1, 2
```

This throws an error since aggregate functions are not allowed within group by statements. How can I work around this to get the count check before the length check?

Thanks!

---

Edit for clarification:

This is one piece of a larger SQL that checks various formatting in a data set. The output is a bunch of unions (one select for each check), each of the form:

```
          check_n  | OK       | count(OK)
          check_n  | DEFECT_1 | count(DEFECT_1)
          check_n  | ...      | ...
          check_n  | DEFECT_m | count(DEFECT_m)
          check_n+1| ...      | ...
```

But for this particular bit, I want to produce the following result:

```
          check_k  | OK       | count(OK)
          check_k  | DEFECT_1 | count(DEFECT_1)
          check_k  | DEFECT_2 | NULL
```

Comment: The way your query is written right now, you don't even need a group by.

Comment: I don't get what you exactly want, can you show some sample data and expected result?
Do yu really want to group by that CASE column?

Comment: Are you sure? I tried running it without the group by and I get "Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group."

Comment: Based on your example there will be two mutually exclusive results: DEFECT_2 or (OK and DEFECT_1) if the counts match, is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to get that result with a simple query, but this should work (though it's definitely not very efficient):

```
sel
     'blah' as x1,
      case when (SELECT count(distinct f1) - count(distinct f2) FROM table) = 0
             then(case when char(trim(f1)) between 1 and 25
                         then 'OK'
                       else 'DEFECT_1'
                  end)
           else 'DEFECT_2'
         end as x2,
       count(x2) as x3
 from table
 group by 1, 2
```

More complicated but also more efficient should be this: calculate all three possible results in a single row and then do a conditional join to a two row table (here using sys_calendar):

```
SELECT 
   x1,
   CASE
      WHEN is_equal = 'N' THEN 'Defect_2' 
      WHEN n = 1 THEN 'Defect_1'
      ELSE 'OK'
   END,
   CASE
      WHEN is_equal = 'N' THEN cnt
      WHEN n = 1 THEN cnt - cntcase
      ELSE cnt
   END AS x
FROM
 (
   SEL 'blah' AS x1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN (CHAR(TRIM(f1))) BETWEEN 1 AND 25 THEN 1 END) AS cntcase,
       COUNT(*) AS cnt,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT f1) = COUNT(DISTINCT f2)
            THEN 'Y' 
            ELSE 'N'
       END AS is_equal
   FROM TABLE
   GROUP BY 1
 ) AS dt
JOIN (SELECT day_of_calendar AS n FROM sys_calendar.CALENDAR WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND 2) AS t2
ON (n = 1 OR (is_equal = 'Y'))
AND x > 0
```